# Fragment not calling onPause or onStop when using replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragmentmanager

I have this odd problem that my fragments are not calling any of the end lifecycle methods like onPause and onStop when I replace it with another fragment.
I replace the fragment like this

```
public static void replaceFragment(Activity activity, int layoutId, Fragment fragment, String title, String shortTitle) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(layoutId, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(title);
    transaction.setBreadCrumbTitle(title);
    transaction.setBreadCrumbShortTitle(shortTitle);
    transaction.commit();
    activity.getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();     
}
```

I think it is somehow keeping my fragment alive even if i popBackStack cause after replacing the same fragment again after it have been shown ones before then it also calls the onStop before onStart?

Comment: Where do you call this method in your code ?

Comment: Its in an abstract class

Comment: Could you show us the code for one of your impacted fragments? Does it have the @Override directive on onPause()?

Comment: Enable logging with FragmentManager.enableDebugLogging(true); and see if that shows anything useful

Comment: It have the @Override and the DebugLogging is telling me the same as in my question :(

Comment: Any chance you've overriden life cycle methods (either in your `Activity` or `Fragment` classes) and forgotten to delegate the call to the `super`? There is nothing wrong with the code snippet in your question, so the problem is probably somewhere in the hosting `Activity` or one of your `Fragment` classes. Without any more details I'm afraid is going to be impossible to further pinpoint the exact issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem :)

It was because my app on tablet added two fragments in one main fragment, and when I then replaced the fragment containing the two other fragment theirs onPause and onStop are not called so by calling theirs onStop in the main fragments onStop I have solved this problem.

Thanks to all for trying to help out i did't know that the method I was using was'n really the problem but that child fragments not are destroyed with their parent!

Answer (score 2):

Using your exact code inside of an abstract class, I can't replicate this issue. I created an abstract class, `ReplaceFragment`.

My `Main` class extends `FragmentActivity` and sets up the content view for the fragment.

Inside the Fragment class, I set up a `ListView`. When a list item is clicked, I'm doing the following:

```
      getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

      // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
      DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
      if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
        details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);
        
        ReplaceFragment.replaceFragment(...);
      }
```

My output in LogCat on each click is:

> 10-07 12:19:07.688: V/FragmentManager(861): remove: DetailsFragment{40527d48 #1 id=0x7f040003} nesting=2
>
> 10-07 12:19:07.688: V/FragmentManager(861): movefrom RESUMED:DetailsFragment{40527d48 #1 id=0x7f040003}
>
> 10-07 12:19:07.688: E/DetailsFragment(861): **Details onPause()**
>
> 10-07 12:19:07.688: V/FragmentManager(861): movefrom STARTED: DetailsFragment{40527d48 #1 id=0x7f040003}
>
> 10-07 12:19:07.688: E/DetailsFragment(861): **Details onStop()**
>
> 10-07 12:19:07.699: V/FragmentManager(861): movefrom STOPPED: DetailsFragment{40527d48 #1 id=0x7f040003}

Post further details of your implementation so that can help you further.

Comment: I have only one Activity in my application so I use this method to replace the fragments inside a container (framelayout).

Comment: The onPause and onStop of the fragment is called when the Activitys onPause or onStop is called. But not when I am replacing it.

Comment: Post additional source and I'll be happy to test your exact use case.

Comment: Well its a normal class that extends fragment. Try to remove the  extends FragmentActivity and the extends ReplacementFragment and you have what i have.

Comment: I am not implementing it its an abstract class and the method is static so I just call ClassName.replaceFragment(...);

Comment: I call the method in a onClick method in a menu in the left side of the screen

Comment: Okay, I appear to have nearly your exact configuration here, and I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: I recall that it have worked before and now it does not. Something have broken it and that is the question why. Does it have anything to do with the manifest or the fragmentmanager? thanks for the help but it seams to be a deeper problem :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38729/discussion-between-mike-and-jeppe-andersen)